# laravel blade confirmation alert for multi language support

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

I am trying to add multi-language to a laravel project.

I am having a problem with applying the confirmation alert.

For example,

```
onclick="confirm( {{  __('Are you sure you want to remove this method? The payment records will not be deleted.') }} ) ? this.parentElement.submit() : '' "
```

in

```
 <form action="{{ route('methods.destroy', $method) }}" method="post" class="d-inline">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{  __('Delete Method') }}" onclick=" confirm( {{  __('Are you sure you want to remove this method? The payment records will not be deleted.') }} ) ? this.parentElement.submit() : '' ">
        <i class="tim-icons icon-simple-remove"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

is not throwing `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error.

But as you can see, ) is there.

please help.

Comment: Missing quotes inside `confirm()`!

Answer (score 1):

brombeer's answer.

'missing qoutes inside `confirm()`'

```
onclick="confirm( '{{  __('Are you sure you want to remove this method? The payment records will not be deleted.')' }} ) ? this.parentElement.submit() : '' "
```

Worked!
Thank you brombeer :)